# What's the difference between сфотографи́ровать and снять?

Tags: глаголы, разница, словарь

What's the difference between these perfective verbs?

Answer (score 3):

«Снять» is a colloquial expression, which literally means "take off", that is, "take [a photo] off", while «сфотографировать» is more formal.

Comment: And of course be careful with you colloquials, as "снять девушек" means something completely different to "сфоткать девушек"! 

Answer (score 3):

In the context of photography, both mean "take a photo" and are pretty much interchangeable, although I feel that photographers themselves tend to use "снять" as their preferred professional term. The derived nouns фотогрáфия and сни́мок meaning *photo* and фотосéссия and съёмка meaning *photo session, photo shoot* behave the same way.

Снять can also be used for shooting videos (снять кинó *to shoot a movie*) whereas сфотограф**и**ровать cannot - it's only used in the sense of taking photographs. There are some inconsistencies, of course, like you can say фотосъёмка and видеосъёмка meaning *photo/video shoot*, but you can use фотосни́мок and NOT видеосни́мок.

Снять also has a lot of other meanings not related to photo and video, see https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C for example.

As for сфотографи́ровать, фотогрáфия and so on, in everyday speech we usually use shorter colloquial forms like сфóтать/сфóткать and фóто/фóтка, which are the most widely used forms in the common language.